# Using jQuery transition animations across static pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, quicksand, history.js

I'm working on a client's website that has a database of products in a table with a menu on the left side.  Currently, clicking on a new menu entry brings up a new set of products on a new page.

The client wants me to change the site such that when a user clicks on a menu entry, the content transitions using an effect like that in the [jQuery Quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html).

However, the Quicksand plugin does not work across page loads.  Do you have any advice on ways I could achieve this effect without rewriting the entire structure of the site?  I had a look at History.js, and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/854622) which provides a bookmarklet to automatically ajaxify a site via History.js.  Prior to this I did not think that was possible, but now I wonder, could I use a technique similar to this to somehow allow the Quicksand plugin to transition between the various pages?

Answer (score 1):

To transition between pages on my customers websites i use jquery ajax calls. i have each page in its own .php file. and then i use $.ajax to bring it up.

For transitions i use Jquery UI that provides some very nice transitions.

And as for the browser history, i use jHash. Its a bit frustrating to use and implement, but if you understand how it works and etc, you will be amazed by its power.

Comment: I would probably use a method like this but the site is already written.  I'm more wondering if there is a simple(r) solution with a large site already written in a non-ajaxy way.

Comment: Im afraid I can't think of any other way. But its really simple to ajaxify your website. All you have to do is get main content of each page, and put them in a seperate file: create_page.php .

Then load the page using:
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "create_page.php",
success: function(page){
$("#divtobeplaced").html(page)
}
})

})
</script>
Alternatively you can also use the jQuery .load event.

[Documentation For Jquery .Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
[Documentation For Jquery .load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)